# npm install settings to display dependencies being installed

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

when running npm install on any project I used to get a result looking like this https://prnt.sc/grns5z

which shows all the dependencies being installed, 
I recently installed `sudo npm install -g react@16.0.0-alpha.6` and `npm install npm@latest -g`

after running these two commands I no longer see the dependencies being installed in yellow text
This is what I see now 
https://prnt.sc/grntzv

Is there a option or setting to display the dependencies being installed like in the first screenshot?

I tried resetting npm global settings with `echo "" > $(npm config get globalconfig)
npm config --global edit` but it didn't work,

Comment: have you checked your package.json file?

Comment: @Antz Yes I tried across many projects, and created new projects just to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try killing any lingering node processes by running these codes:

```` sudo kill -9 ```pgrep node``` ````

`rm -rf ./node_modules`

`npm update`

then you should try running the codes again.

*******:~$ `sudo npm install -g react@16.0.0-alpha.6`

It should show you this after it installs successfully

```
+ react@16.0.0-alpha.6

added 16 packages in 35.241s
```

and

*******:~$ `sudo npm install npm@latest -g`

```
/usr/bin/npm -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/usr/bin/npx -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
+ npm@5.4.2
updated 1 package in 15.393s
```